# Express Gateway adding scopes to endpoints

Tags: express-gateway

I have a working autoregister gateway function, which fills my gateway-config.yml.
We will be using scopes so I added scopes to postData, but it doesn't add scopes.

```
const postData = JSON.stringify({
      host: '*',
      path: currentKey,
      methods: methodsByPaths.get(currentKey),
      scopes:
        Scopes[`${process.env.ENDPOINT}${currentKey.split('/').join('')}`],
    });
```

- Some console log of currentKey and the Scopes[...]

/api/users  -  undefined

/api/token  -  undefined

/api/createProject  -  PROJECT-MANAGER

Also, when the scope is undefined, it adds the endpoint, if it is not undefined (project-manager) it didn't even add the endpoint. I tried hard codding scopes to something and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t send scopes in the POST request; they are strictly internal to Express Gateway.

When a user is authenticated by Express Gateway, the authentication credential defined in Express’s config.yml file the user is authenticated against should include the list of scopes the user has access to; these are used internally by Express Gateway to control access to endpoints.